Windows Users with Removable disk (Disk management) admin rights for Raritan Java Application
I have a windows problem about right management and GPO. I don't know if there is a solution...
My problem is simple, I have a Java application to connect to a KVM Raritan DKX3 dominion
This application is a .jnlp
This application allows to take the control of the KVM target and to "share" the USB key from the physical computer (where the .jnlp is executed) with the KVM target.
When we share this USB KEY (removable disk), the java application will unmount the usb key and mount a (virtual?) removable disk.
It works very well with the administrator account.
When I use a limited user account, the application works but this USB sharing is not working. the application is showing an access right error.
If I launch this application with admin right (Terminal as administrator and launch the .jnlp) it is working well.
I'm not sure what is the windows component used by the application to mount a virtual removable disk. I guess this is the "Disk manager" component.
The Raritan documentation doesn't give much information except "You need administrator right".
My problem and Question: I don't want that my user knows the administrator password, I would like the user run the jnlp and the application has the authorization to mount this virtual removable disk (Disk manager right). Is it possible with windows? I tried some GPO related to Removable disk but without any good results :(
Any ideas?

The vendor needs to update their application such that it doesn't require elevation, or find out from them what actual privileges and permissions are required to make it work without requiring elevation.
